# Ensure system accounts are non-login

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, shell

I don't understand this egrep statement here. Why do we need to use `-v "^\+"` since the file starts with userid

```
egrep -v "^\+" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '($1!="root" && $1!="sync" &&
$1!="shutdown" && $1!="halt" && $3<1000 && $7!="/usr/sbin/nologin" &&
$7!="/bin/false") {print}'
```

Comment: The grep is unnecessary, btw ... `awk -F: '(!/^\+/ && $1!="root" && $1!="sync" &&
$1!="shutdown" && $1!="halt" && $3<1000 && $7!="/usr/sbin/nologin" &&
$7!="/bin/false") {print}' /etc/passwd` does the same job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do we need to use -v "^+" since the file starts with userid?

Because In Ye Olden Days, a line beginning with `+` was how we imported information from [NIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service), the "Network Information Service". You can see an example of the syntax in the Linux [NIS HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NIS-HOWTO/settingup_client.html#AEN280).

This service is still supported by Linux, so things that interact directly with `/etc/{passwd,shadow}` need to be aware of the syntax.